# How to recover data from an encrypted 1TB WD MyBook drive that was formatted?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

We accidentally formatted an external hard drive with extremely important files on it and we're desperate to find any solution. We had it encrypted with a password using Western Digital's software. Then, the drive was formatted by using "Unlock.exe" and blanking the drive, and then the drive was formatted as exFAT. How do we get back our files? Even if it's just some of them? Is there any Western Digital software to help us with this?

Comment: No offense, but you don't... you have no possibility of getting back files from a volume that was encrypted, then blanked and formatted with a standard file system. A professional forensic data recovery service would only have a bout a 50/50 chance of recovering the data if they know your password, the data hasn't been overwritten other data, and it would costs thousands of dollars. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: What if we re-created the encryped drive with the same password and then scanned inside of that drive? Would that work?

Comment: No, the encryption key is based on a password you provide and a randomly generated key that is stored on the drive, the two together are required to decrypt the volume. Re-creating the encrypted drive would have a different encryption key, gaining nothing.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you know if WD's drives work this way?

Comment: By the way, external hard drives have about the lowest endurance of any digital storage means in common use. Having critical data stored only on an external hard drive is insane.

Comment: All files of any importance should have at least one backup copy. Files that are "extremely important" should have at least 2 backup copies. Many people have 3. Any drive, new or old, can fail at any time, often without warning or apparent reason. Data can be lost for many other reasons as well.

Encrypted disks are no exception. You just need to take appropriate precautions with the backup copies.

Comment: @AaronFranke Yes, that is how it works... If the encryption worked any other way, what good would the encryption be then?

Comment: @acejavelin Do you have a source for this? I want to know for sure that we're screwed. And, the encryption would be good because it would keep out everyone who didn't have the password, but this method keeps out everyone.

Comment: There's an old vulnerability in [WD](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/10/20/western_digital_bad_hard_drive_encryption/) that did mention the method used (a random number involved) and an [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44730/how-secure-is-wd-mypassport-lock) answer also inferred from the doc about the method.

As for the benefit, intermediate key allow [changing password](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88984/encrypting-with-passwords-encryption-of-key-vs-data) without re-encrypting the whole drive. The random key helps against rainbow table attack

Comment: No, this is how it should work in order to have an encryption that makes any sense. You don't want to have a n bit password (probably) in order to access the content of the drive. So in order to give you that convenience stuff is derived from your password. Depending on how the formatting tools you used work you might have overwritten any preexisting data already. Did you put files on the exFAT after formatting? You could try to contact WD or a company like OnTrack which might be your best bet but is probably going to be expensive.

Comment: Is this also the case for a WD MyBook drive?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not looking for an argument, but do you have any evidence to support the claim that external hard drives *"have about the lowest endurance of any digital storage means in common use"*?  Yes, a mishandled one may have issues, but a well-cared-for unit should have the same endurance as the hard drives in millions of computers in use around the globe.

Comment: Can you advise what you mean by "unlock.exe" formatted and blanked the drive ?  Did this process take seconds or hours ?  (There seems littel info on it on the Internet, but from what I can see, it is not a disk formatting program - it must either decrypt the drive and remove the passphrase (in which case you may be able to recover data off it - this process would take a long time), or it would simply remove the key and reset the drive - this would be a quick process and you would have no chance.   Try getting a Linux recovery disk and using photorec to see if it recovers any data.

Comment: @davidgo It was a fast process, took seconds. Nothing shows up in Linux, I have a full installation on my computer as well with a Windows dual-boot.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Internal hard drives have extremely low endurance to begin with, only about three years on average. External hard drives are worse because they often get lost, dropped, left in a hot car, and so on.

Comment: @Aaronfranke - unfortunately you need to make other plans to rebuild or re-acquire the data, as its not recoverable from the hard drive.  If the process took seconds it could not have converted the data from encrypted to unencrypted, so it would have been removing the (internal) decryption key.  No decryption key, no way of recovering the data from the disk.